# How to position the Toast message

Tags: flutter, toast

I want to display the toast message at the `centre/top` of the screen. By default it comes at the bottom of the screen.

How to change the position of the `flutter toast`?

Comment: did you check this page https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast ? it seems with positionedToastBuilder

Comment: hm, didn't get any working reference; but seems its still under development - https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/259

Comment: can you at least show what you have try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use Toast Package from here](https://pub.dev/packages/toast)

and this how to use it inside your code:

> Toast.show("Toast plugin app", context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity:  Toast.BOTTOM);

Change the gravity property to the desired place

> Toast.TOP (or) Toast.CENTER (or) Toast.BOTTOM